# RangeValidator Currency value can't contain more than 2 digits after decimal?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

Framework 4.0 Asp.net application

When I run the code  I got a error "The value '999.9999' of the MaximumValue property of 'RangeValidator' cannot be converted to type 'Currency'.

Below is my code:

```
<asp:RangeValidator Runat='server' ControlToValidate='textEdit' 
    MinimumValue='0.0001'
    MaximumValue='999.9999' Type='Currency' 
    ErrorMessage='Should be between 0.0001 and 999.9999' id="idValidtor" 
 display='None' />
```

Please explain me is currency value can't contain more than 2 digits after decimal?
Unless how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: please post the code you used to convert to currency?

Comment: <asp:RangeValidator Runat='server' ControlToValidate='textEdit' MinimumValue='0.0001' MaximumValue='999.9999'           Type='Currency' ErrorMessage='Should be between 0.0001 and 999.9999' id="idValidtor" display='None' />

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`RangeValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/f70d09xt%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) uses the [`NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyDecimalDigits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencydecimaldigits%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) property to determine if the string can be converted to a currency, otherwise it will throw your exception. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/f70d09xt%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> when a RangeValidator control's Type property is set to
>   "Currency", the MinimumValue and MaximumValue properties must be
>   provided in a format such as that described in
>   NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyDecimalDigits, **otherwise an exception is
>   thrown**.

The default for most cultures (incl. `InvariantCulture`) is 2 (arabic countries have 3 but none 4).

So what culture are you using? If it is important to store more decimal places than two in a currency, then you could use a custom `NumberFormatInfo` in this page:

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var customCulture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
    var nfi = (NumberFormatInfo)customCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
    nfi.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 4;
    customCulture.NumberFormat = nfi;
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;
}
```

(note that you need to add `using System.Globalization;` at the top)

Comment: Thanks your quick reply.This is my-code . Is there a way to tell range validator to validate up to 4 decimal points when it comes to type Currency?                                                       
<asp:RangeValidator Runat='server' ControlToValidate='textEdit' MinimumValue='0.0001' MaximumValue='999.9999'  Type='Currency' ErrorMessage='Should be between 0.0001 and 999.9999' id="idValidtor" display='None' />

Comment: @user1118064: I've already edited my answer to show how you can change this setting.

Comment: This is what i am looking for. Thank you very much.Its working. I have put this in to HttpModule, Context_BeginRequest and now its available for all site pages and requests.

Comment: Just stumbled on this answer for a real work of mine. Thanks @TimSchmelter Note that this is also true for the decimal separator. If you use the comma for decimal then the constant string for MaximumValue and MinimumValue should reflect the regional settings.