# RangeValidator cannot be converted to type 'Currency'

Tags: asp.net

I use rangeValidator for textBox for money: 
My code is this :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxValueFrom" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

            <asp:RangeValidator ID="ValueRangeValidator" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"
                ErrorMessage="Value between 0.01 and 9999999.00"
                MinimumValue="0.01" MaximumValue="9999999.00" Type="Currency"
                 ControlToValidate="TextBoxValueFrom"
                EnableClientScript="False" Display="Dynamic"
                Text="*"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

But this give to me error : The value '9999999.00' of the MaximumValue property of 'ValueRangeValidator' cannot be converted to type 'Currency'.

I tried to replace currency with Double but the error is :

```
 `The value '9999999.00' of the MaximumValue property of 'ValueRangeValidator' cannot be converted to type 'Double '.`
```

What i've done wrong ?

Comment: Can you try with a , instead of a . and try without the fraction part at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RangeValidator Currency value can't contain more than 2 digits after decimal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643347/rangevalidator-currency-value-cant-contain-more-than-2-digits-after-decimal)

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to specify the "m" suffix on the numeric values to indicate currency type; e.g. MinimumValue="0.01m" MaximumValue="9999999.00m"

The suffix "m" actually stands for money (i.e. currency).