# RangeValidator currency validation makes no sense

Tags: asp.net, validation, rangevalidator

I'm having some issues using a RangeValidator in ASP.NET 4.5. The issue I'm facing is trying to validate a range of currency values.

Let's say I have the following RangeValidator:

```html
<asp:RangeValidator ID="_rngValCustomAmount" runat="server" 
CssClass="error-message" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid amount." 
ControlToValidate="_txtCustomAmount" MinimumValue="10.00" 
MaximumValue="500.00" Type="Currency" />
```

When I enter a value of '450' the validation is passed, and I can submit the form. However, if I enter '$450' then the validation fails, even though I have set the `Type` property to `Currency`.

So, then I thought, OK, maybe I need to enter a currency Minimum and Maximum value, however when I change the control to:

```
MinimumValue="$10.00" 
MaximumValue="$500.00"
```

I get the following .NET exception:

> **The value '$500.00' of the MaximumValue property of '_rngValCustomAmount' cannot be converted to type 'Currency'.**

I don't really want to have to resort to using a CustomValidator for this, so that I don't have to write a JS function for something that should exist as the RangeValidator supports the currency type. Can anyone point out what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Set the current thread UI culture and no need to add $ for both min and max values of RangeValidator.

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643347/rangevalidator-currency-value-cant-contain-more-than-2-digits-after-decimal - explains the current thread UI culture wrt to the RangeValidator when using Currency